# using fgets in a while loop causes invalid read after a few loops

Tags: c, pthreads, fgets

I'm trying to read in a list of hostnames and put them on a stack for another thread to perform DNS lookup on. However, my requester function currently only seems to want to read the first 5 lines of the file. After this it segfaults. When running with Valgrind, it produces the following output:

```
==30737== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==30737== Copyright (C) 2002-2015, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==30737== Using Valgrind-3.11.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==30737== Command: ./multilookup 1 1 resolve.txt results.txt input/names1.txt
==30737== 
Starting Main
creating thread info
creating mutexes
creating threads
Seting up output files
opening inputFile
Creating requester threads
Entering Requester While loop 1
Creating resolver threads
waiting for 1 requesters to end
Got line: facebook.com
Pushed hostname facebook.com
about to lock the threadfile
Got line: youtube.com
Pushed hostname youtube.com
about to lock the threadfile
Got line: yahoo.com  
Pushed hostname yahoo.com
about to lock the threadfile
Got line: wikipedia.org
Pushed hostname wikipedia.org
about to lock the threadfile
Got line: msn.com
Pushed hostname msn.com
about to lock the threadfile
==30737== Thread 2:
==30737== Invalid read of size 8
==30737==    at 0x50C4B09: fgets (iofgets.c:47)
==30737==    by 0x400EF9: Requester (multilookup.c:27) 
==30737==    by 0x4E416B9: start_thread (pthread_create.c:333)
==30737==  Address 0x8 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
==30737== 
==30737== 
==30737== Process terminating with default action of signal 11 (SIGSEGV)
==30737==  Access not within mapped region at address 0x8
==30737==    at 0x50C4B09: fgets (iofgets.c:47)
==30737==    by 0x400EF9: Requester (multilookup.c:27)
==30737==    by 0x4E416B9: start_thread (pthread_create.c:333)
==30737==  If you believe this happened as a result of a stack
==30737==  overflow in your program's main thread (unlikely but
==30737==  possible), you can try to increase the size of the
==30737==  main thread stack using the --main-stacksize= flag.
==30737==  The main thread stack size used in this run was 8388608.
==30737== 
==30737== HEAP SUMMARY:
==30737==     in use at exit: 1,928 bytes in 4 blocks
==30737==   total heap usage: 6 allocs, 2 frees, 7,048 bytes allocated
==30737==  
==30737== LEAK SUMMARY:
==30737==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==30737==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks 
==30737==      possibly lost: 272 bytes in 1 blocks
==30737==    still reachable: 1,656 bytes in 3 blocks
==30737==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==30737== Rerun with --leak-check=full to see details of leaked memory
==30737== 
==30737== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==30737== ERROR SUMMARY: 1 errors from 1 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
Killed
```

The referenced line 30 in the output is the `while(fgets(...))` line in the function, I believe this to be the offending portion of code:

```
char hostname[1056] = "";
printf("Entering Requester While loop %i\n", numFiles);
while(done < numFiles)
{
  pthread_mutex_lock(&(threadInfo->file_mutex[fileIndex]));
  while(fgets( hostname, sizeof(hostname), fileArray[fileIndex]))
  {
    ...
  }
}
```

I'm currently running the code with only 1 requester thread, so only 1 thread is created besides main. The requester function can be seen here:

```
void* Requester(void* thread_Info)
{
  //printf("Entering Requester\n");
  struct thread* threadInfo = thread_Info;
  int numFiles = threadInfo->fileCount;
  int serviced=0;
  int done = 0;
  FILE** fileArray = threadInfo->threadFile;
  int fileIndex = threadInfo->startIndex;
  struct stack* hostnameList = threadInfo->hostnameList;
  char hostname[1056] = "";
  printf("Entering Requester While loop %i\n", numFiles);
  while(done < numFiles)
  {
    pthread_mutex_lock(&(threadInfo->file_mutex[fileIndex]));
    while(fgets( hostname, sizeof(hostname), fileArray[fileIndex]))
    {
      strtok(hostname, "\n");
      printf("Got line: %s\n", hostname);
      pthread_mutex_unlock(&(threadInfo->file_mutex[fileIndex]));
      //printf("Checking stack\n");
      while(stackIsFull(hostnameList))
      {
        //printf("Stack was full\n");
        pthread_mutex_unlock(threadInfo->hostnameList_mutex);
        usleep(10000);
        pthread_mutex_lock(threadInfo->hostnameList_mutex);
      }
      //printf("stack was empty\n");
      stackPush(hostnameList, hostname);
      printf("Pushed hostname %s\n", hostname);
      pthread_mutex_unlock(threadInfo->hostnameList_mutex);
      //printf("unlocked hostnameList_mutex\n");
      printf("about to lock the threadfile\n");
      pthread_mutex_lock(&(threadInfo->file_mutex[fileIndex]));
      //printf("locked file_mutex\n" );
    }
    printf("finished file %i\n", fileIndex);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&(threadInfo->file_mutex[fileIndex]));
    //printf("unlocked file_mutex\n" );
    done++;
    fileIndex = (fileIndex+1)%numFiles;
    //printf("incrimented fileIndex\n");
  }
  printf("exited while loop\n");
  return NULL;
}
```

I'm passing a struct of the thread info to requester, the struct looks like this:

```
struct thread{
  FILE** threadFile;
  FILE* logFile;
  bool* requestersAlive;
  int startIndex;
  int fileCount;
  struct stack* hostnameList;
  pthread_mutex_t* hostnameList_mutex;
  pthread_mutex_t* file_mutex;
};
```

and it is initialized in main like this:

```
FILE* inputFile[dataFileCount];
for(int c = 5; c<argc; c++)
{
  inputFile[c-5] = fopen(argv[c], "r");
}

struct thread requester_info[requester_threads_count];
for (int i=0; i<requester_threads_count; i++)
{
  requester_info[i].threadFile = inputFile;
  requester_info[i].logFile = requesterLog;
  requester_info[i].hostnameList = &hostnameList;
  requester_info[i].hostnameList_mutex = &hostnameList_mutex;
  requester_info[i].file_mutex = infile_mutex;
  requester_info[i].startIndex = i%dataFileCount;
  requester_info[i].fileCount = dataFileCount;
  pthread_create(&(requesters[i]), NULL, Requester, &(requester_info[i]));
}
```

I'm running out of ideas of what could be wrong, any help is very appreciated.

Comment: How did you create the `threadInfo->threadFile` array?

Comment: I just added that to the post!

Comment: And how is `requester_info` defined and initialized? And `inputFile`?

Comment: Added that too!

Comment: First thing to notice is that you don't check if `fopen` returns `NULL`, so you may be passing `NULL` to `fgets`. Also your `threadInfo->startIndex;` are initialized to 0, 1, 2, etc. Do `dataFileCount` and `requester_threads_count` have the same value? If `requester_threads_count` is larger than `dataFileCount`, then some threads might be accessing `fileArray` out of bounds. And would you please do a better indentation of your code, add a few blank lines, it's so hard to read it.

Comment: please post a [mcve] so we can reproduce the problem